# Is there any information about the end of Krishna Dwaipayana - Veda Vyas?

Tags: vyasa

As the question says, are there any references about the end of Krishna Dwaipayana - Veda Vyas, especially about when it happened?

Answer (score 3):

Accordingly to famous beliefs, *Krishna Dwaipayana*, or famously *Ved Vyasa* has not died. He is considered to be among the *Chiranjivis* (extremely long aged or nearly immortal). There are various [Chiranjivis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiranjivi):

```
Ashwatthama
Bali (& his son Banasur)
Hanuman
Kripa
Parashurama
Vibhishana
Vyasa
Jambavan
Markandeya
Devapi
Maru
Saptarishis
Bhusunda
```

There are many speculations about his whereabouts but nothing is for sure.

Answer (score 2):

> Krishna Dvaipāyana will be one of the Saptrishis in 8th (or next) Manvantara. - [Vishnu Purana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp076.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Although traditionally we consider only 10 avataras for Sri Vishnu, in reality he has had as much as 32 or 33 avataras, and Krishna Dwaipayana Veda Vyasa is one of them. It is correct that he does not undergo death being a Chiranjeevi (immortal). Secondly, in the story of Sri Raghavendra Swami, it is said, 3 yrs before his maha-samadhi, once when he was in a field teaching his students, he saw Krishna Dwaipayana Veda Vyasa flying by the skies who, after noticing the swamiji, is said to have indicated the time of swamiji's maha-samadhi by making some signs with his hand. (Showed 3 fingers 3 times which means, in 3 yrs, 3 months and 3 days from that time, swamiji should enter brindhavana). Read this in the charitra of Raghavendra Swamiji.